# Can't find Crescius for An Axe to Find

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

I took the mission to bring back the ancient nordic pickaxe from Glover Mallory but Crescius isn't anywhere to be found! I have already spoken to him once in his old mine but after that he just dissapeared. When I follow the quest arrow it leads me to his house and the arrow just points at nothing then. I have used the detect life spell to see if he is invicible becausr of a bug or something and I have even looked if he became a zombie working on the stone near Raven Rock, but NOTHING! 
Please help me I'm desperate!!

Comment: You might want to edit your question's title to something more descriptive of the issue.

Answer (score 3):

If you are on PC, you can try the following commands in the console

`prid xx01827B` where xx is the load order number of Dragonborn, most likely 02 or 03, followed by `moveto player`. If that doesn't help, try `disable`, `enable`, `moveto player`. If that didn't help either, try `kill`, `resurrect`, `moveto player`. You can also force this quest to complete with `setstage DLC2RR03Intro 200`, since it's not very important, and give yourself the pickaxe with `player.additem xx0398e6 1`.

If the above commands didn't help or you aren't playing on PC, you can try going away for 30+ days and seeing if things have worked out when you return. The last option is to load an earlier save.

Comment: I play it on the ps3 so commands are imppssible...but sleeping for 30 days or more will do the trick? Does it reset it? Already thank you for the answer!

Comment: It might work, it might not.

Comment: I'm gonna try it right now nothing else but sleep for awhile

Comment: I did it but can you tell me what happens with the game when you sleep for 30 days? Does it reset the npc's or something?

Comment: It didn't work ): gonna start on a new character since I have no other choice.

Comment: There really is no point starting over just because of that - the ancient nordic pickaxe is not a unique item and the quest has no real consequences.

Answer (score 1):

Just sounds like a bug, try sleeping or travelling back to skyrim then back again to Raven Rock and see if that helps. Good luck :)

Comment: I already slept once just so try it but it didn't work and I also fasttravelled to skyrim and back but that didn't work either. Maybe the 30 days sleeping thing works? I only slept for 1 hour or something.

Answer (score 0):

IMO the NPC's reset every 72 hours. I base this on being the time frame I have observed for shop keepers to refresh their gold as well as inventory. You could check the mine if you have completed the quest since I have seen him down in the mine as well as in the Wretched Netch.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find Crescius Caerellius: Check your quests. If you have not completed "*The Final Descent*" you will NOT be able to find him.

You must complete it, then he will be sitting in his house.